# Can't get the Address from Geocoder

Tags: android, google-geocoder

I have created simple code just for getting address from string location. Code brakes at starred line. Why ?? if I print the exception : Service not Available

```
List<Address> address;
    String myAddress = "Vilnius";
    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                        System.out.println("coder : :" + coder);
                        **address = coder.getFromLocationName(myAddress, 1);**
                        ObjLoc1adr = coder.getFromLocationName(ObjLoc1String, 1);
                        ObjLoc2adr = coder.getFromLocationName(ObjLoc2String, 1);
```

Comment: Check if `Geocoder.isPresent()` is returning true.

Comment: by the way, i wrote his code mounth ago, and it was working. nothing changed. And now it is not working..

Comment: Some emulators don't do reverse geocoding, it depend on the API version number. From memory, API level 7 is OK.

Comment: im using 19 api, on my nexus 5

Comment: its very strange that mounth ago it was working

Answer (score 1):

Because of this you should always wrap that code in a try block to catch an IOException. There is no guarantee that the Geocoder always find a location or the service is reachable. This hasn't to be a fault of your code or device. A simple connection problem or timeout is enough to brake your App.

To be save have something like this:

```
if(GeoCoder.isPresent()) {

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
    String myAddress = "Vilnius";
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    try {
        address = geocoder.getFromLocationName(myAddress, 1);
        if (!addresses.isEmpty()) {
            Address address = list.get(0);
            // do something with your address
        } else {
            // No results for your location
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```